# Mostrar cuantas veces se repite un numero en varios arreglos

Tags: c#, array

tengo que desarrollar una simulacion de un juego de dados, el juego consiste en 5 dados y 5 tiros, hacerlo con 5 arrays distintos y luego mostrar cuantas veces se repiten los numeros al finalizar

La realidad es que lo tengo casi todo hecho, porque pude hacer que me muestre por ejemplo las repiticiones de numeros de un array solo, pero yo necesito que sea de todos en una sola suma

Paso a mostrar lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
        int[] Dado1 = new int[5];
        int[] Dado2 = new int[5];
        int[] Dado3 = new int[5];
        int[] Dado4 = new int[5];
        int[] Dado5 = new int[5];
        int[] Acum = new int[10];

        Random rnd = new Random();

        Console.Write("Bienvenido Jugador, para ejecutar el tiro de los dados presione enter.\n\n");

        Console.Write("Tiro 1:  ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Thread.Sleep(350);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Dado1[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write(Dado1[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\nTiro 2:  ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Thread.Sleep(350);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Dado2[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write(Dado2[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\nTiro 3:  ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Thread.Sleep(350);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Dado3[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write(Dado3[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\nTiro 4:  ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Thread.Sleep(350);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Dado4[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write(Dado4[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\nTiro 5:  ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Thread.Sleep(350);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Dado5[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write(Dado5[i] + " ");
        }

        foreach (int num in Dado1)
        {
            Acum[num]++;
        }
        for (int ir = 0; ir < Acum.Length; ir++)
        {
            if (Acum[ir] > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ir + " = " + Acum[ir] + " veces");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

En el foreach muestro lo que necesito, pero solo para 1 dado (arreglo), yo necesito mostrar lo mismo pero de todos los tiros juntos, no uno por uno

Comment: asi como hiciste para uno, porque no podrias hacerlo para los 5?

Comment: Por que en el ejemplo presentado por el profesor, muestra el numero y las veces que se repitio, no tiro por tiro. Podria hacerlo asi a mi manera como lo descubri, pero temo a que no lo acepte

Comment: y si en lugar de foreach, usas un for comun y corriente? igual, la solucion que te podamos dar aca podria no ser aceptada por tu profesor.

Comment: un for que lea los 5 arrays al mismo tiempo ?... Si estoy pensando que los ejercicios que esta dando son cerrados a su manera, lo cual es entendible, pero tambien siendo nuevo entiendo tambien que hay varias formas de llegar a 1 una posible solucion verdad?

Comment: exacto... un for que lea los 5 al mismo tiempo y los vaya sumando a tu gusto... y lo otro, tambien es cierto.. hay mas de una forma de terminar cada ejercicio...

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @gbianchi, ahora como podria hacer para la pregunta aca, pienso en ponerme a investigar sobre tu respuesta y sino, enviarlo a mi manera como lo tenia hasta ahora... Y bueno, si me lo aceptan bien :P

Comment: solo eliminala hasta que tengas una duda mas clara.. o puedes solucionarlo y escribir vos mismo la respuesta!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola yo haria lo siguiente:

Una clase que se llame dado y que contenga el arreglo de las caras y una funcion para llenar las caras

```
public class Dado {

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int[] Caras { get; set; } = new int[5];

    public Dado(string nombre) {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void ActualizarCaras() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < Caras.Length; i++) {
            Caras[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            Console.Write(Caras[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego la logica

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {

        //Crear el arreglo con los 5 dados
        List<Dado> Dados = new List<Dado>() { 
            new Dado("1"),
            new Dado("2"),
            new Dado("3"),
            new Dado("4"),
            new Dado("5")
        };

        Console.Write("Bienvenido Jugador, para ejecutar el tiro de los dados presione enter.\n\n");

        //Arreglo donde se guarda la repetición de los numeros 
        int[] cantidad = new int[6];

        //Por cada dado
        foreach (var dado in Dados) {

            Console.Write($"Tiro {dado.Nombre}:  ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Thread.Sleep(350);

            //Creamos las caras de los dados
            dado.ActualizarCaras();

            //Guardar las repeticiones
            foreach (var cara in dado.Caras) {
                cantidad[cara-1]++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        //Imprimir
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"El número {i+1} se repite {cantidad[i]} vece(s)");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]